# Distribute identical data points horizontally instead of overlapping them

Tags: recharts

I have three data series as input to a scatter chart. In total there are 6 data points. However, my chart shows only 3 because the other 3 have identical values with one another so they sit exactly on top of each other.

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want:
[image]

```
const A = [
  {
    x: new Date("01-01-2023"),
    y: 130,
  },
  {
    x: new Date("03-01-2023"),
    y: 2500,
  },
  {
    x: new Date("07-01-2023"),
    y: 5000,
  },
];

const B = [
  {
    x: new Date("03-01-2023"),
    y: 2500,
  },
  {
    x: new Date("07-01-2023"),
    y: 5000,
  },
];

const C = [
  {
    x: new Date("07-01-2023"),
    y: 5000,
  },
];
```

and my scatter chart:

```
 <ScatterChart
                        width={400}
                        height={220}
                      >
                        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                        <XAxis
                          dataKey="x"
                          type="number"
                          name="date"
                          domain={["dataMin", "dataMax"]}
                          tickFormatter={(tick) =>
                            new Date(tick).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
                              year: "numeric",
                              month: "numeric",
                              day: "numeric",
                            })
                          }
                         
                        />
                        <YAxis
                          dataKey="y"
                          type="number"
                          name="price"
                          tickFormatter={(tick) => `$${tick}`}
                         
                        />

                        <Legend />
                        <Scatter
                          name="A"
                          data={A.map((item) => ({
                            x: item.x.getTime(),
                            y: item.y / 100,
                          }))}
                          fill="#8884d8"
                        />
                        <Scatter
                          name="B"
                          data={B.map((item) => ({
                            x: item.x.getTime(), //convert date to epoch because we need a number for x-axis
                            y: item.y / 100,
                          }))}
                          fill="#82ca9d"
                        />
                        <Scatter
                          name="C"
                          data={C.map((item) => ({
                            x: item.x.getTime(),
                            y: item.y / 100,
                          }))}
                          fill="#a8325c"
                        />
                      </ScatterChart>
```

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible in recharts. You could try using `Customized` and `Dot`, but you'll have to do a lot of the computation yourself/almost rebuild the scatter chart functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I figured what I'm trying to do is not a "Scatter Chart" in the truest sense.